# Is it better to attach data to a deferred object as a property, or send the data alongside the deferred object to a function that does the resolving?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, future, deferred

I have two functions.  One function creates an Ember deferred object and sends it to the other function, along with some data.

Should that data be sent along side the deferred object, and separate, or should it be attached to the deferred object and send as a single parameter?

So here's an example of the functions (not verbatim, just hopefully a clear enough example for the question):

```
function startSomething(data) {
    var defer = Ember.RSVP.defer();
    defer.data = data;

    defer.promise.then(
        //pass
        function(result) {
          //do stuff
        },
        //fail
        function(result) {
          //do stuff
        });

    doOtherThing(defer);
}

function doOtherThing(defer) {
    var data = defer.data;

    //do something with the data
    var result = //some result of messing with data

    //if success
    defer.resolve(result);
}
```

I'm creating the deferred object first, and then setting a data property on it, then sending it to the other function.

Would it be more appropriate to do:

```
doOtherThing(defer, data);
```

or

```
doOtherThing(defer) //with data attached as a property
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this is probably mostly an opinion, I think that most seasoned Javascript developers would agree that it's generally better to pass a separate argument for your `data` than it is to put the data on the promise object.

This isn't really a promise-specific issue at all.  If you can pass the data separately, then keep it separate from objects that it doesn't have anything to do with.  There is no advantage and plenty of possible disadvantages to putting foreign data on an object you don't control.  In your specific case, what if the promise implementation already has a property named `.data` or decides to use such a property in the future?  You could have just broken the implementation.

In your specific case, you could just pass the `data` as a second argument like this:

```
function startSomething(data) {
    var defer = Ember.RSVP.defer();

    defer.promise.then(
        //pass
        function(result) {
          //do stuff
        },
        //fail
        function(result) {
          //do stuff
        });

    doOtherThing(defer, data);
}

function doOtherThing(defer, data) {

    //do something with the data
    var result = //some result of messing with data

    //if success
    defer.resolve(result);
}
```

---

If you had limitations and could only pass one argument for some reason (e.g. some API interface that only has one context variable), you could put both the promise and the data on a different object and pass that single object, dereferencing each of the promise and your data separately and still keeping them separate from each other.  IMO, this would be more desirable than putting the data on the promise.

Comment: It might be odd, but I decided to vote my answer as opinion based, because, well, it is.

I've accepted your answer, though, since you answered my question really well.  I've decided to leave the question just in case anyone else has the same concern.